# CXF method declaration for form

Tags: java, forms, cxf

This might be a simple one but I just can't seem to nail it down.
I have a simple form with 2 fields, text and file, i.e.

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="textfield">
  <input type="file" name="filefield">
</form>
```

what is the CXF method declaration that catches that?

Thanks!

Comment: CXF? Are we both talking about WebServices, SOAPs and WSDLs?

Comment: Nadav, to clarify, you mean [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) not [Adobe ColdFusion](http://adobe.com/coldfusion), right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create simple web service like this:

```
@WebService
public class SimpleWs
{
    @WebMethod
    public String upload(String textfield, byte[] filefield) {
        // ...
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

and the follow [these instructions](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/a-simple-jax-ws-service.html) at CXF's site.